# Try to setup an 1155 token to be render with all its metadata (name, description, image) to opensea.io

Tags: nft, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I have the smart contract below

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/extensions/IERC1155MetadataURI.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";


contract Token1155Blockco is ERC1155 {
    string internal baseMetadataURI;
    mapping (uint256 => string) public tokenIdsToIpfsId;
    mapping (uint256 => uint256) public tokenIdsToCount;
    function uri(uint256 _id) public override view returns (string memory) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked(baseMetadataURI, tokenIdsToIpfsId[_id]));
    }


    function tokenURI(uint256 _id) public view returns (string memory) {
        return string(abi.encodePacked(baseMetadataURI, tokenIdsToIpfsId[_id]));
    }

    function _logURI(uint256 _tokenID) internal view returns (string memory) {
        string memory tokenUri = tokenIdsToIpfsId[_tokenID];

        return string(abi.encodePacked(baseMetadataURI, tokenUri));
    }

    function _logURIs(uint256[] memory _tokenIDs) internal {
        string memory baseURL = baseMetadataURI;
        string memory tokenUri;

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _tokenIDs.length; i++) {
          tokenUri = string(abi.encodePacked(baseURL, uint2str(_tokenIDs[i]), ".json"));
          emit URI(tokenUri, _tokenIDs[i]);
        }
    }

    // function contractURI() public pure returns (string memory) {
    //  return "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmf5T7vL7WHkPYhKVDYupSYw5unqaoLRNEE6tjuV8upHSy";
    // }

    function _setBaseMetadataURI(string memory _newBaseMetadataURI) internal {
        baseMetadataURI = _newBaseMetadataURI;
    }

    constructor() ERC1155("Token1155Blockco") {
        _setBaseMetadataURI("https://ipfs.io/ipfs/");
    }

    function setURI(string memory newuri) public {
        _setURI(newuri);
    }

    function name() external pure returns (string memory) {
        return "Token1155Blockco";
    }

    function symbol() external pure returns (string memory) {
        return "TK1155BC";
    }

    function setTokenIdIfpsId(uint256 id, string memory ipfsId) public {
        tokenIdsToIpfsId[id] = ipfsId;
    }

    function mint(uint256 id, uint256 amount, bytes memory data) public
    {
        tokenIdsToCount[id] += amount;
        _mint(msg.sender, id, amount, data);
    }

    function getCountPerId(uint256 id) public view returns (uint256){
        return tokenIdsToCount[id];
    }
   
    function uint2str(uint256 _i) 
        internal
        pure
        returns (string memory str)
    {
        if (_i == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        uint256 j = _i;
        uint256 length;
        while (j != 0)
        {
            length++;
            j /= 10;
        }
        
        bytes memory bstr = new bytes(length);
        uint256 k = length;
        j = _i;
        while (j != 0)
        {
            bstr[--k] = bytes1(uint8(48 + j % 10));
            j /= 10;
        }
        str = string(bstr);
    }
}
```

I have implemented several function such as `function uri(uint256 _id) public override view` or `function tokenURI(uint256 _id) public view` but opensea.io is not presenting the Name, Description and Image as I am setting them up on minting

Answer (score 0):

So the ERC1155 Standard requires a uri function which returns a static URL `https://yourhostserver/{id}` open sea knows to replace the {id} with your tokenId converted to hexadecimal and padded to 64 bytes, your host server should return a JSON object with the required information in the root

```
{ name: "token name", description: "token description "}
```

also don't forget to refresh metadata on the top right of your token page on open sea